# Checking unique value for an attribute in Magento 2 work incorrect?

Tags: magento, attributes, magento2

When I try save attribute with two same values. I got error - The value of Admin must be unique.

I checked M1. M1 allows you to save attribute with same values. It is ok, because table `eav_attribute_option_value` has auto increment field `value_id`, and you can save two same values, but they will have two different `value_id` and table `eav_attribute_option` has auto increment field `option_id` and will save two different values too.

In M2 added new class `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Validate.php` which purpose - checking value is unique or not.

Who can explain, for what was to be implemented this checking?

Comment: I found answer. Magento 2 attribute has option `Unique Value`. But this option works incorrect.

Comment: can you show me how you set attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I just learned how unique value works in Magento 2. Unique means the value will be unique among all the other values of that attribute. So not being unique doesn't mean that you can add duplicate values to your attribute.

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/attributes-product.html#advanced-attribute-properties

> **Unique Value**
>
> scope setting. Unique value should be enabled for any attribute that
> is used as an ID number. For example, because SKU is used to identify
> products throughout the hierarchy, it has a unique value with a global
> scope. Options: Yes / No> Requires the attribute value to be different from all other values
> entered in the same attribute, within the context of the